# SQL Query combine related data from 2 rows and show the most recent created

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have a SQL Server table like this:

```
Id         Value         Created         EntryId
--------------------------------------------------
1          NULL          2018-01-01      A
2          10            NULL            A
3          NULL          2018-01-02      B
4          20            NULL            B
5          NULL          2018-01-03      C
6          10            NULL            C
```

and so forth

The `EntryId` field basically relates the entries. For example items from row 1 and 2 belong to same entry, 3 and 4 to a different entry, 5 and 6 to a different entry but 5 and 6 entry is related to 1 and 2 entry because the value is the same.

So what I need is create a query that will output something like this:

```
Value        Created
-------------------------------
10           2018-01-03
20           2018-01-02
```

if there are multiple records where Value is the same then pick the most recent one.

EntryId is the field that connects a Value and when was created. Basically in the example above value 10 was entered twice but I need the most recent one

I tried:

```
SELECT Value, MAX(Created), EntryId
FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY EntryId, Value
```

PS: I need to run this in a view so I cannot create temp table

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Made an edit to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two queries with two group by's. This would help (Please note that create table statement is just for demonstration purposes):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE t
>     ([Id] int, [Value] varchar(4), [Created] varchar(10), [EntryId] varchar(1))
> ;
>
> INSERT INTO t
>     ([Id], [Value], [Created], [EntryId])
> VALUES
>     (1, NULL, '2018-01-01', 'A'),
>     (2, '10', NULL, 'A'),
>     (3, NULL, '2018-01-02', 'B'),
>     (4, '20', NULL, 'B'),
>     (5, NULL, '2018-01-03', 'C'),
>     (6, '10', NULL, 'C')
> ;
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 6 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> create view V1 as 
> select value, max(created) Created from (
>   select max(value) value, max(Created) Created, EntryId
>   from t
>   group by EntryId
> ) t2
> group by value
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> select * from v1
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> value | Created   
> :---- | :---------
> 10    | 2018-01-03
> 20    | 2018-01-02
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=417bac01f234dad65173a6ecb268605b)*

Comment: BTW: I need to run this in a view so cannot create table

Comment: please check my answer again. Create table just simulates your table and it is just for demonstration.

Comment: @Simonare: my bad !

Comment: Alvaro this is the correct way of doing it. I don't see any downside of this query, and your downvote is non-sense

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with one aggregation:

```
select tv.value, max(tc.created)
from t tv join
     t tc
     on tv.entryid = tc.entryid and
        tv.value is not null and
        tc.value is not null
group by tv.value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this - substitue 'YourTable' with the name of your table!

```
select 
    Value,
    max(b.Created) as Created
from YourTable a    
    inner join (select EntryId, max(Created) Created from YourTable group by EntryID) b
        on a.EntryId = b.EntryId
where Value is not null
group by Value
```